# vector graphics logo for laser cutting

Tags: feature-request, design

I like the new B.SE design. My first thought was that the logo is inspired by bike headbadges, so it can be used as a real-life headbadge.

[image: Bicycles.se Logo]

With current computerized machining technology it wouldn't be too difficult/costly to make, too.

Please provide a SVG version of the logo, so that we can laser-cut it and use it proudly on our bikes.

Comment: Sure. Do you just want the basic shapes in vector, or do you want the additional shading too?

Comment: @Jin: A basic shape is good for laser-cutting out of stainless steel, which was my first idea. The shades add a lot of complexity.

Comment: I'd like one of with shading, and one without, or one with, and I can modify as needed.  I was already considering making a mold for an investment cast belt buckle. i have a homemade 3d printer that could do a form for the mold, with the right source files. A .ai file works for me.

Comment: @Tadeusz - Your proposal has left the nest! :)

Answer (score 4):

We're trying to figure out a better place to host promotional type of files(vector, wallpaper, flyers etc), where we can easily deploy updates. Once we find a solution I'll be posting the files. For now if you're interested in the vector files, email me at jin@stackexchange.com

Comment: There are now many materials available for 3d printing, so with the assumed surface texture. One may even print in steel or titanium, but probably some silver like cheaper material would look well. Many bicycles only have painted logo at front.