# The Water Bottle (Here it is!)

Tags: discussion

[image]

Who needs messaging when you've got an eye-popping design.

These bottles will be included in a care package for high-rep users (more on that later), packaged with stolen bike contest prizes, and made available at the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/) as soon as they are available (mid-September).

One awesome swag piece down. Let's move on to [**another**](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/local-bike-shop-lbs-stack-artifact).

Comment: What's the word on this? Can we buy these?

Comment: @NeilFein - We've got 'em. I was going to wait until top user packages go out to distribute the bottles, but it appears top user packs won't go out until X users earn X rep (a secret metric, the community team tells me... and this site is getting close). So, stand by. Actually, for only a week longer. I will get bottles in the store before the end of next week.

Answer (score 2):

Well done on getting this done!

One question, what happens to non-US customers of the SE store, do they bother to order?

I personally don't order stuff* online if it has to come from the U.S. - not even from amazon. I don't think I am alone in this, although lots of people do buy from over the pond.

The UK punches above its weight in the online world, I believe a lot of readership comes from good ole Blighty.

You might want to approach Chain Reaction Cycles or Wiggle to carry these bottles. They will need copy + picture for the product page. You know the trade price for bottles - they pay less than you do, so I doubt that SE will be making their first million from CRC/Wiggle selling these bottles. You'll be doing well if they pay carriage - expect that to be 'volumetric' rather than 'by gross weight'.

Comment: I agree with this. The main difference seems to be postage. UK shops will ship to Aus for less than $10 usually. But US shops often add $45-$50 in postage!